# How to install lamp server with php 5.3 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp

Is it possible to successful run php5.3 on ubuntu 16.04 or not?
I have an PHP application that required only php 5.3 version.

1. Please let me know what version of ubuntu is required to run PHP 5.3
2. How can I install lamp server with php 5.3 and all its dependent modules (apache server mysql etc)

Comment: PHP 5.3 is EOL. Nobody packages it. You'll have to install from source.

Comment: Do you know any references for this? if yes, please share...

Answer (score 1):

In case you really need to do it, use phpbrew.

My steps to install php5.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 (will work for 14.04):

Install phpbrew https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/wiki/Quick-Start

**To build 5.3.24 :**

```
sudo phpbrew install 5.3.24  +bz2 +calendar +cli +gd +ctype +dom +iconv +fileinfo +filter +ipc +json +mbregex +mbstring +mhash +mcrypt +pcntl +pcre +pdo +phar +posix +readline +sockets +tokenizer +xml +curl +zip +mysql +debug +apxs2
```

**/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load** file must contain

```
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.3.24.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

**To enable module for apache2:**

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6 ; sudo a2dismod php7.0 ; sudo a2enmod php5 ; sudo service apache2 restart
```

**To install gd extension**

```
phpbrew use php5.3.24
phpbrew ext install gd --with-gd=shared,/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-gmp=shared,/usr --with-jpeg-dir=shared,/usr --with-xpm-dir=shared,/usr/X11R6 --with-png-dir=shared,/usr --with-freetype-dir=shared,/usr --with-vpx-dir=shared,/usr
```

Comment: It's generally better to include those steps here in your answer, rather than including a link.